# Border-radius bug on <a> in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css

Seeing that `<div>` elements render border/border-radius correctly, but any `<a>` or `<button>` that has a background, border and border-radius set shows the background color or image as a square, and only the border is round. Tried setting `<a>` & `<button>` to `display: block` or `display: inline-block` but that didn't work.

Is there a known workaround?

Here is a link to the computed style from Webkit: https://gist.github.com/773719

[image]

Here is the computed style from IE9 dev tools:
[image]

**Update**
Using the filter:; or -ms-filter:; property to have gradients in IE make the background break out of the defined border-radius.

Comment: Is this only in IE9? If not, can you post some CSS?

Comment: Of course it's only in IE9.  IE8 doesn't support `border-radius`.

Comment: Yes, only IE9. Webkit/Firefox is working correctly. Will update post with CSS.

Comment: IE9 is a beta product. This mean there could still possibly be bugs in the product that could negatively affect how code is rendered.

Comment: I don't understand why the IE9 team hasn't removed filter:progid...gradient, and replaced it with background:gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#4b90e5), to(#0e4b94));...normal CSS...the way it should have been from the very start

Answer (score 3):

I've found this excellent blog posting that shows how you can use SVG gradient sprites to fix this particular issue: http://abouthalf.com/2010/10/25/internet-explorer-9-gradients-with-rounded-corners/

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to nest the the gradient inside another element with the border radius AND an overlflow.
This is less than ideal, but its all css. no hacks.

Outside of this, using a background image works pretty well for ie.

```
<div class="corner">
   <div class="grad">button</div>
</div>


<style>
.corner,
.grad{
   height:50px;
   width:250px;
   }
.corner{
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   overflow:hidden;
   }
.grad{
   border:1px #659300 solid;
   background: #659300; /* old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #659300 0%, #6F9B00 50%, #528200 51%, #6CA501 100%); /* firefox */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#659300), color-stop(50%,#6F9B00), color-stop(51%,#528200), color-stop(100%,#6CA501)); /* webkit */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b1cc00', endColorstr='#518e00',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Running in to this as well. The 'filter' based gradient isn't actually a background image as it is with CSS3 gradients it's an extra layer. The IE team obviously hasn't gotten round to clipping these filter layers to the rounded corners. Strange because it's pretty obvious that folks are going to be making buttons like this.

Mapping legacy features against the new ones must be pain. It could be better for them to just implement gradients in CSS. I'd rather add a prefix than add legacy filters.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this is to use [CurvyCorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/), a javascript solution. It works all the way back to IE6, but struggles with gradiated backgrounds. If you are using a block coloured background however it will work fine, and has handled all border types I've thown at it so far. The website says you need to call it, but somehow I've found it seems to work simply by including the .js and using css3 border-radius attributes in the css.

Comment: also, sorry, i want to reply to what @Nasir said, but cant yet - however, the reason the IE team have said they don't yet support css3 features is because the css3 specs arent finalized yet. its pretty weak, but theyre basically planing on 'catching up' and implementing css2 properly before they begin on 'experimental' technologies. until css3 is standard we're going to be in for a lot of frustration asking "why didnt they...?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator. It recommended to use this code to disable filter in IE9:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

This should solve your problem.