# jQuery does not render corners well in Windows Phone 8 phone gap application

Tags: css, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

I have a Phonegap application for Windows Phone 8 that uses web pages inside. I make a button inside a `<div>` element with `data-role="footer"` option inside that div. Also button is an `<a>` element with `data-role="button"` option inside it.

The button is not rendered always well, there appears some corner issues on it, the corner is not rounded but it is a 90 degrees white ancle instead of blue nice rounded corner.

Is there any known issues on Windows Phone 8 that it does not support some HTML5 features and / or jQuery features?

**Edit 1:**

Sources (essential parts):

TestButton.java:

```
public class TestButton extends Widget {
       private static TestButtonUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(TestButtonUiBinder.class);

       interface TestButtonUiBinder extends UiBinder<AnchorElement, TestButton> {}

       AnchorElement mAnchor;

       public TestButton() {

            mAnchor = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);

            setElement(mAnchor);

            mAnchor.setAttribute("data-role", "button");
       }
}
```

..and TestViewImpl.java:

```
    @UiField
    TestButton mBackButton;

    @Override
    public TestButton getBackButton() {
        return mBackButton;
    }
```

.. and TestViewImpl.ui.xml:

```
  <b:TestButton ui:field="mBackButton" dataIcon="arrow-l"
                title="{mI18n.back}" toolbarRight="true" />
```

**Edit 2:**

[Border-radius bug on <a> in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652793/border-radius-bug-on-a-in-ie9) points that similar issues may arise due to the not mature nature of css3 when some combinations of css3 tags do not work well together.

Now, my button renders at Firefox as follows:

```
<a style="font-weight: bold;" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-hover-b ui-btn-up-b"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Back</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a>
```

Comment: Does it render the same on IE10 desktop? Could you please post your sample on jsfiddle so that I can take a look.

Comment: IE10 desktop renders fine.

Comment: Tested on jqm 1.3 default theme under cordova 2.5, renders correct (WP8 emulator).

Comment: IE10 Mobile is different from EI10 desktop. Emulator is different from a device. Have anybody tested this with a mobile device called Windows Phone 8? The connection on my phone is slow and the rounded corners render slowly, having before a white angle. Sometimes the loading fails or sth, because the white angle stays. It is curious, that the corners are not always loaded well, but content is always (text etc .)

Comment: @mico have you tried it on any other devices?

Comment: Well, Android ones, yes, and iOS. It has been tested in another wp8 but I don't know if the issue is also there. Android and iOS worked well, I will ask the work mate to answer about wp8.

Comment: According to **Metro guidelines**, I suppose that important elements of Metro design are exactly edges without radius. I'm gonna try it on a WP8 device and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be wp8/Lumia specific problem and it happens quite randomly, so that not every button is affected by this phenomenom.

Comment: jQuery-mobile is version 1.2.0, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Can you post your markup?

Comment: According to your edit 2, if color gradient is the problem, then override class `.ui-btn` by setting `background-color` and `background-image` to `none` followed by `!important`.. Unfortunately i don't have windows phone to test it. Check this custom button http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/2Y7ze/

Comment: Please add your answer as an Answer, not just Comment. Maybe someone else on same situation may make use of Your answer, and can find it easier from Answers than just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless anyone suggests any workaround, the current investigations of mine show the result is that this is a bug in the jQuery itself and the workaround should be found outside jQuery or fixing the jQuery itself.

***Source:** Please have a look at jQuery demo page, e.g. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/buttons/buttons-themes.html and observe e.g. `Swatch "a"` from the demo page with a wp8 device. You'll observe the weird corners. I tested Lumia 920.*

***Solution:** Wait for 1.4 and hope the best, or manually combine 1.2 and 1.3 and pick best parts of both.*

**Edited solution:** Yes, 1.4.0 is there, and the problem seems to be solved :) They changed the entire look and feel, so the problem went away.

Comment: jQuery 1.3.1 test page renders better than 1.1.1 (http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/widgets/buttons/) but the disabled buttons there are still horrorous: even worse shadows, this time even misplaced ones, are present.

Comment: jQuery 1.3.1 seems to vanish this problem from buttons, but introduces it to other elements and the result at first glance seems to be equally irritating, so at least now, I won't update to that version. I don't know then, if there is a version somewhere between where the buttons are corrected, but other theme still not broken.

Comment: No, I use 1.2.1.min version on code currently and that was the original version. There is no other version between. Waiting for the 1.4 :)

Comment: have you tried overriding the styles as i mentioned my comment to your question?

Comment: Actually I did not get the idea very easily (to where I should put that, because the button is used in many places) and now I am satisfied with waiting new version, because this is not important feature for now and I am able to live without and I am busy with other things.

Comment: like this http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/2Y7ze/, and load css for specific browsers. anyway, it's good that you got a workaround now, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this resource](http://mobilehtml5.org/), Windows Phone 7.5 and above fully supports CSS 3 Basic styling (opacity, backgrounds, text effects, rounded corners), meaning the rendering issues you are experiencing are not due to incompatibility.

You may want to try using the `-ms` [prefix](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) to ensure full IE 9+ CSS3 functionality, e.g:

```
div {
    -ms-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
}
```

*(CSS prefixes were adopted by browser manufactures to implement their version of draft CSS3 features. As the standard matures, these prefixes in many cases are becoming obsolete. In other cases they are still required; [read here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/dropping-ms-vendor-prefixes-ie10/) for their continued usage in IE10.)*

Comment: I am not so sure about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162890/which-border-radius-property-will-work-in-ie9 says that at least ie9 does not use any prefixes. I also manually added to my code everywhere that `-ms-` version, but with no help. Actually, also your source says, that this specific one (border) does not have any prefix.

Comment: Yeah, IE has no prefix for border-radius (to be fair, IE have no prefix for **almost** every CSS3 property).

Comment: I linked to article stating the use of the `-ms` prefix, I didn't say it was the answer but was worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem trying to render a circular button in the WebBrowser component in WP8 with `border-radius:` it turned out square.

Solution: Add:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

to the top of the `<head>` section